# Update with order

Tags: sql-server

I am building a dynamic SQL statement

This my code

```
declare @TmpDRGs varchar(max)
set @TmpDRGs = 'CREATE TABLE #TmpDRGs  ( ur_number varchar(10) '


declare @Temp1 as table (diagnosis varchar(10))


insert into @Temp1 (diagnosis)
select DISTINCT  diagnosis
from PtsDiagnosis
order by diagnosis

update @Temp1
set @TmpDRGs = @TmpDRGs + ',[' + diagnosis + '] tinyint'



select @TmpDRGs
```

The output is

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpDRGs  ( ur_number varchar(10) ,[X90] tinyint,[N73] tinyint,[P84] tinyint,[B08]...
```

I want them to be in order like this

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpDRGs  ( ur_number varchar(10) ,[B08] tinyint,[N73] tinyint,[P84] tinyint,[X90]...
```

I used order by in the building `@Temp1`  table but still getting them in wrong order

I cannot order by the update statement

so how to put these columns in order?

Comment: FYI my suggested question/answer to your previous (now deleted) question does contain info on how to construct column lists dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @B VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE TABLE #B ( ur_number varchar(10),'

SELECT @B += STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',['+ CAST(diagnosis AS VARCHAR) + '] tinyint'
FROM PtsDiagnosis 
ORDER BY diagnosis 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')+')'

PRINT(@B)
```